# Grails application in openshift

Tags: grails, jboss, openshift

I am trying to deploy my grails application on an openshift server. I have created an instance using command "rhc app create MyApp jbossews-2.0". When I ssh to the server, I see a jboss folder but no tomcat folder. How can I deploy my .war file onto the server?

Comment: This provides an excellent resource on how to setup grails with open source: https://www.savillians.com/tech/2013/01/24/grails-on-openshift/

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Docs on how to deploy a binary file](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html-single/User_Guide/index.html#sect-Application_Deployment) will help you with this, however what the docs do not say is that with Tomcat the **deployments** directory is called **webapps** but they work the same way (except for the marker files, tomcat does not use those).

You may want to check out https://github.com/gssOpenShiftsupportExamples/JavaSample as it shows an example of how to do this with JBoss (the same thing will work for Tomcat if you change the directory as denoted above).